# JQuery duplicating javascript to document using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

In the left menu is use this script to load a new page in a div:

```
$("#button").live('click',function(){
                $("#content")
                .html(ajax_load)
                .load("page.html");
            });
```

In the page.html there's some javascript to add some UI elements using ajax (also with jquery).

When i click the same left menu item 5 times (so the divs loads 5 times), it seems that the javascript in page.html gets copied. when i call a function in the page.html its get executed 5 times!!

How to fix this?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more code, like the function you're calling in the dynamically loaded content, and the code that calls that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use live() for anything inside page.html the event handler will persist even if a new page.html is loaded that's probably why you have the same execution multiple times.

Comment: So the best thing is NOT to use .live, what should i use then?

Comment: .bind() or the shorthand .click(), .live() will keep watching for new items that matches the expression even after being executed, .bind just matches when it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

What javascript executions are happening in "page.html" Are they event bindings? If so, look at the .live() method and pull the javascript out of your page.html file.  When the elements of the page.html are brought into scope they will be correctly handled by the bindings in the live() method.

If you are doing something else, please provide more context.